# Constraints for Email adress in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is there an annotation for springbote that makes it possible to only allow certain emails as email.

The email should only end with @ companyname.com

Comment: Not that I know of but, you can make your own annotation & validator logic in a new class like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050936/jpa-validation-of-email-string-collection)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already answered by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370879/javax-validation-constraints-email-in-springboot)

You can use the **@Email** constraint from **javax.validation.constraint** .

Per default the regular expression of the email constraint allows everything. So for you case following can be done:

```
@Email(regex = "\W*((?i)@companyname.com(?-i))") 
private String mail;
```

If you wished you can also modify the default constraint violation message.

Remember of course to add the needed dependency if not already provided e.g

> ```
> implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.4.0'
> ```